# Handling race condition in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, servlets

Hoping someone can point in the right direction as to why this isn't working:

```
    Session session = factory.openSession();
    session.refresh(customer);
    session.close();
    Boolean paid = customer.hasPaid();
    if (paid) {
        System.out.println("test1");
    } else {
        System.out.println("test2");
    }

    if (!paid && paymentInput.getRequestType() == PaymentInput.RequestType.NEW) {
        session = factory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        customer.setPaid(true);
        customer.update(customer, customer.getId());
        tx.commit();
        session.close();
        System.out.println("updated");

        PaymentProcessor.pay(customer);
    }
```

What I want is for the first request to hit "test2", then "updated", and for all other requests to hit "test1" and miss the second conditional. If I fire multiple requests quickly after each other currently it's hitting "test1" and entering the second conditional multiple times. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

The only way for other tests to not hit "test1" is for them to begin their transactions *after* line 16 – `tx.commit();` – has completed its work. What is your goal here? If you have requests that must *assume* the transaction is committed, you'll have to force them to *wait* until that assumption holds true. This is typically accomplished with some sort of lock.